# Disabling core-dumps, when filesystem is almost full

Tags: linux, rhel, core-dump

We make good use of the core-dumps and don't want to disable them completely. At the same time, we don't want them to fill up the filesystem.

Can Linux be told to disable them automatically, when the filesystem, to which they would've been dumped, is above the specified threshold -- like 90%?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't built in, but you can configure Linux to invoke a program of your choice when a core dump happens. The program receives the core dump on its standard input, and it can decide what to do with it. This is configured via `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`. See “Piping core dumps to a program” in the [core(5) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) for details.

For example, Ubuntu pipes core dumps to [apport](https://launchpad.net/apport/) to notify users and offer to report a bug when a core dump happens. You can make your own program that checks the disk space and only writes to a file if it's above a certain threshold.

Beware that this program runs as root, so whatever it does can potentially be exploited by a program that deliberately crashes. For example, a program could crash in a directory where it has no writing permission and trick the core dumper program into writing a core file in that directory. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to use this interface safely unless you write all core dumps in a dedicated directory instead of the crashing program's current directory.

Comment: Sigh, I was hoping for something, a non-root user could set for his own programs. But, maybe, our admins will accommodate, thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a way for this core-writing program to know the _size_ of the dump in advance? Before reading it from stdin?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to know the size in advance. I suspect the kernel doesn't calculate the size and just generates data on the fly. You can start writing and remove the file if it becomes to large. It won't be worse than the kernel's enforcement of the core size limit, which is to stop writing when the file reaches the limit.

Comment: With cooperating users, you could arrange that core dumps are only left in certain cases when debugging programs, and have a cron job that removes old cores. Not exactly what you asked, but that way the cores won't fill up the disk. You may also want to arrange for core files to be in non-backed-up space.